# formatting a number string with commas

Tags: c#

I have a string number that I want to format to have commas.

For example, the string 12345 needs to be displayed as 12,345

How do I accomplish this?

This is embedded in html.

Comment: check `NumberFormatInfo.NumberGroupSeparator `

Comment: Since its good to have an answer for everything on SO I'm not going to suggest that this could be easily looked up on MSDN.

Comment: @Mike Quick clarifying question - is your number already stored in a `string` type? Can we see what you have tried so far?

Comment: @EtherDragon yes it is, i have already tried a couple of these answers `String.Format("{0:n0}", sAnswer)` and `value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` dont work

Comment: @Mike What did `String.Format("{0:n0}", sAnswer)` output?

Comment: EtherDragon your answer will not work if you do not declare your starting variable as an int this however will work `int sAnswer = 12345;
var newAnswer = string.Format("{0:N0}", sAnswer);` `"12,345"` will be the output

Comment: @Mike Hmm. I'm not sure that there is an easy answer since your data is already a string. Have you considered refactoring your project so that the data is an int instead? It seems as though you are using an incorrect data-type.

Comment: @DJKRAZE sAnswer cant be an int, assigned like so: `QuestionAnswer answer = (from a in tabItem.answers where a.QuestionId == question.QuestionId select a).FirstOrDefault();
                            string sAnswer = answer == null ? " " : answer.CalculatedRolledUpAnswer;`

Comment: Mike I think that you need to refactor your question and put in exactly what you are trying such as the comment.. put that code in the question section.. you are are getting tons of examples but if you are part of the blind leading the blind then it's obvious you will get incorrect suggestions to help in your potential solution

Comment: ok so how can i convert this data-type to an int?  `int val = int.Parse(sAnswer);` wont work, nor will `int val = Convert.Int32(sAnswer);`

Comment: what is the value of sAnswer? is it 12345 or null?

Comment: its 12345, but can be null

Comment: so why are you saying that 12345 when using the example in the earlier comments didn't work..?

Comment: sAnswer can be any number or null, the answer earlier in the comments didnt work

Comment: Mike I just tested this guys answer, `value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture));` as it is it will not work but if you assign a new varable `var newvalue = value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);` you get a string representation that's formatted

Comment: Lets start over.. what is QuestionAnswer.. can you show the type or class..? you need to provide a lot more information in your initial question otherwise you will get a lot of answers that are not helpful and it will start to frustrate you ..please add all relevant code if needed that pertains to the issue at hand

Comment: the QuestionAnswer class is too long to confusing and will probably add to the confusion.

Answer (score 6):

The [canonical MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
Group separator specifier:
2147483647.ToString("##,#", en-US) -> 2,147,483,647
2147483647.ToString("##,#", es-ES) -> 2.147.483.647

Scaling specifier:
2147483647.ToString("#,#,,", en-US) -> 2,147
2147483647.ToString("#,#,,", es-ES) -> 2.147
```

or, for a lighter touch, see this [great article from years ago](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

Answer (score 2):

Check out the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c899ak8.aspx)

```
value = 1234567890;
Console.WriteLine(value.ToString("0,0", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)); 
// Displays 1,234,567,890
```

Comment: got the error "CultureInfo does not exist in current context" changing to `System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture` gives the error 'no overload for method ToString takes 2 arguments'

Comment: @Mike Make sure `value` (or whatever variable you're using) is declared as an `int` and not an `object`.

Comment: it has to be an object

Comment: @Mike then you should cast / convert it to an `int` or use `string.Format("0,0", value)` or similar alternatives as others have suggested.

Answer (score 1):

```
string str = string.Format("{0:n2}", 12345);
Console.WriteLine(str);
Console.Read();
```

Note: that I have used n2 in string.Format which means you want upto 2 digits after decimal. if you don't want any digit after decimal you can set 2 to 0

Answer (score 0):

```
int answer = 12345;
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("{0:n0}", answer));
```

Using `Console.WriteLine`'s built in formatter:

```
int answer = 12345;
Console.WriteLine("{0:n0}", answer);
```

Comment: `string sAnswer = 12345; String.Format("{0:n0}", sAnswer)` returns `12345`

Comment: Because you're starting out as a `string`, you should start out as a number  e.g `int`.  Check out my edit.

Comment: oops guess i failed to mention, this c# is imbedded in html, console.writeline wont work

Comment: `String.Format` should.

Comment: it seem to work, returns 12345

Answer (score 0):

See [Standard Number Formatting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx).

```
int number = 12345;
number.ToString("N0");
```

Comment: will not work Poke.. something like this will however `            `int number = 123456;
var strNumber = number.ToString("N0");`

Answer (score 0):

To display a number with formatting, you'll need to use the ToString() function to format.

Example:

```
int value = 123456;
value.ToString("N0")  // Displays: 123,4556 as a string.
```

More information can be found here:  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx

Comment: value should be a string

Comment: Zachary that answer is incorrect the output does not display 123,4556 did you actually run that not to mention you have a typo in your answer

Comment: this will work however 
`int value = 123456;
 var newValue = value.ToString("N0");`